# Ignoring warning by #pragma

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pragma

How can I disable XCode warning `Format string is not a string literal` in the code below?

```
- (void)testRemovingOldCode {
    NSMutableDictionary *oldRequestDict = [[[OldConfigManager sharedManager] feedURLForKey:kStatItemFixtureDetailURLKey] mutableCopy];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:oldRequestDict[kURLKey], //Warning: "Format string is not a string literal"
                           @"Param1",
                           @"Param2",
                           @"Param3"];
}
```

I already tired (without success):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
```

Comment: Ideally, you should use only string literals as format strings. Why are you trying to silence the warning? fix the code!

Comment: This isn't my code. I am fixing the old code and making unit test to make sure old and new code behave in the same way.

Comment: did you try to block it using `-Wformat-nonliteral`?

Comment: Thanks. Warning has dissapeared. Do you know why "-Wall" didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Wall` doesn't include all warnings, it includes only a specified set of warnings. You might be more successful with `-Weverything`, however, it's always the best to find the exact warning you want to block. In this case `-Wformat-nonliteral`.